# Loop through only certain collections (Shopify)

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I'm working on a new Shopify theme but am getting stuck on one thing. I want to create a shop page that

- Displays collections, but not *all* of them: I want to show only the
  collections that a) contain products, OR b) that have a certain
  metafield set to 'true' (= a metafield indicating it is a 'fixed
  collection' i.e. should be displayed regardless of whether the
  products in it are out of stock)
- Paginates these collections by 20
  (because there are a lot of collections in the store - paginating
  them decreases load time)

This is what I've got as Liquid code (simplified for explanation purposes):

```
{% paginate collections by 20 %}

{% for collection in collections %}

{% assign fixedCollection = collection.metafields.collections.fixedCollection %}

{% if collection.all_products_count > 0 or fixedCollection == true %}
<div class="collection">
// collection contents (title, image etc.)
</div>
{% endif %}

{% endfor %}

{% if paginate.pages > 1 %}
{% include 'pagination-custom' %}
{% endif %}

{% endpaginate %}
```

The issue I'm having is that each page doesn't always contain 20 collections - it's usually less. Because it loops through 20 collections each time but only displays the ones meeting the conditions set by the 'if' statement.

Is there a way to limit the for-loop in some way, so it only loops through certain collections? Or does someone have a better solution for this?

Grateful for any help on this!

Comment: Did you try with the where filter: https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/where/

Comment: @AliceGirard I didn't know about 'where' yet, will see if I can find a solution using that! Thank you!

Comment: I don't think it will work, because it seems the 'where' filter does not accept logical operators. {% assign available_collections = collections | where: "all_products_count", 1 %} works (shows only the collections containing 1 product, {% assign available_collections = collections | where: "all_products_count", > 1 %} gives an error. Open to suggestions...

Comment: Unfortunately this is the only filter I see to "pre" filter the collection array.